# How to paste selected items from a list box in VB.net to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vb.net, listbox

I have a list box populated from SQL database, I would like to export the selected items from the list box to an excel sheet.  What I can't work out is how to past each selected item from listbox in different cells. I have the code to drop down a row each time but cant figure out how to put it together with the selected items block of  code.

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim NewExcel As New Excel.Application
    NewExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim SelectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToList

    For Each selectedItem In SelectedItems
        NewExcel.Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    Next

    'Do
    '    NewExcel.ActiveCell.Value = counter
    '    NewExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate()
    '    counter += 1
    'Loop Until counter = 10

    NewExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change this line NewExcel.Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.SelectedItem  ...   to this ...  counter +=1: NewExcel.Range("A" & counter).Value = SelectedItem.ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line as Bilai suggested and it works perfect.

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim NewExcel As New Excel.Application
    NewExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim SelectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToList


    For Each selectedItem In SelectedItems
        counter += 1 : NewExcel.Range("A" & counter).Value = selectedItem.ToString()
    Next


    NewExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```